# The reason the advantage of Single conductor transmission line be changed to non-singular conductor transmission line

Tags: power, transmission-line

Question:
If Single conductor of EHV(Extra high voltage) transmission line be changed to  non-singular conductor of EHV transmission line,there are some advantages about this changing

1.Decrease the potential gradient in the surface

2.Decrease the inductance of transmission line

3.Increase the capacitance of transmission line

4.Improve Corona discharge

5.Improve radio interference

It is easy to understand the reason of "3.Increase the capacitance of transmission line ",does anyone know the reason about the other advantages?

Answer (score 0):

For 2., the lower inductance means lower loss.

There are two main sources of losses in high power transmission lines.  One is the I^2*R  (resistive) loss, and the other is the loss caused by the self inductance of the transmission line.  Hence reducing the inductance lowers the loss.

Note - eliminating the inductive losses is a big advantage of DC transmission systems.

Comment: why does the lower inductance mean lower loss?